# specifying python environment variables for ant

Tags: python, ant

Update: Forgot that sysproperty is only for java.

```
<target name="uploadFile">
        <pathconvert property="orchestration.properties" refid="orch.config" />
        <exec executable="python" failonerror="true">
            <env key="PYTHONPATH" value="${basedir}/lib/python"/>
            <arg value="${basedir}/upload.py"/>
            <arg value="${basedir}/file.txt"/>
        </exec> 
</target>
```

Inside the lib/python directory is a custom python package i want to include when ant runs the exe.
How do I do that? It's not in python, so I can't add it to the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I've solved this. Python path works, but I forgot to set new environment. If you don't set a new environment, it automatically reverts back to the old one.

If you ever want to run a python command from ant, but have modules in your basedir, and not the python directory, this is how you do it.

```
<target name="uploadFile">
        <property environment="env"/>
        <pathconvert property="orchestration.properties" refid="orch.config" />
        <exec executable="python" failonerror="true" **newenvironment="true"**>
            <env key="PYTHONPATH" value="${basedir}/lib/python"/>
            <arg value="${basedir}/upload.py"/>
            <arg value="${basedir}/test1.txt"/>
        </exec> 
</target>
```